# Reading data from file into array then outputting data into another file

Tags: java, arrays, file, printwriter

Need some help figuring this out. 
I want to input data from data.txt into bsorted.txt with it sorted using bubbleSort.

I need to generate random numbers and letters into a data file and the read them into an array and output this data after sorting to another text file.

I am receiving a `NoSuchElementException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source) at SortingExample.main(SortingExample.java:257)
```

**Code:**

```
class dataFile {

public static void dataFile() {
    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("data.txt");
        String alphaNumerics = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890";
        String t = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        t += alphaNumerics.charAt((int) (Math.random() * alphaNumerics.length()));
    }
        writer.println(t);
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error accessing file.");
        System.out.println("Reason was: "+ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

class SortingExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    dataFile.dataFile();

    Scanner bscan = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
    PrintWriter bsorted = new PrintWriter("bsorted.txt");
    StringType[] strings = new StringType[2000];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
        strings[i] = new StringType(bscan.nextLine());
    }

    Sort.bubbleSort(strings);
    bsorted.println("Bubble Sort number of comparisons: " + Sort.bubbleComp + "\r\n" + "Bubble Sort number of exchanges: " + Sort.bubbleEx + "\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        bsorted.println(strings[i].toString());
    }
    bsorted.close();
   }
}
```

As anyone some ideas to help me?

Comment: Post your exception too and it will give people a good place to start in helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `Scanner.hasNextLine()` is true before you move on to read on the next line through scanner. This would help you identify if you've reached your End Of File marker safely.

Hence your `for loop` would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    if (bscan.hasNextLine())
        strings[i] = new StringType(bscan.nextLine());
}
```

Alternatively, handle it within your try and catch for `NoSuchElementException`

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        strings[i] = new StringType(bscan.nextLine());
    }
} catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
    // Do Nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the loop is going around more times than you have lines in the file.

You probably have less than 2000 lines in your data.txt file, but the for-loop still tries to go around 2000 times and read another line from that file each time.

I recommend you figure out how many lines are in data.txt and go around the for-loop that many times.

Try this code to determine the number of lines:

`LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("data.txt")));`

`lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);`

Then all you have to do is go around your loop `lnr.getLineNumber()` times.

Answer (score 0):

Per your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    t += alphaNumerics.charAt((int) (Math.random() * alphaNumerics.length()));
}
    writer.println(t);
    writer.close();
```

It appears you append everything to one string, and write it out once as one big line. Put another way, you have 2000 elements concatenated into one string.

Your scanner is looking for 2000 lines, so it fails when it only sees one.

My suggestion is to write out many lines as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    t = alphaNumerics.charAt((int) (Math.random() * alphaNumerics.length()));
    writer.println(t);
}

writer.close();
```

Off topic, but there are many conventions that give me pause from an OO standpoint, such as a lower case class name (dataFile), a method name that isn't verb-like (dataFile)

Comment: I actually did that edit, I guess I had to delete data.txt for it to refresh.

Comment: I fixed a few things, now the data in data.txt is already sorted from some reason.